# Grabbing a list of all files (and parent folders) from Google Drive

Tags: c#-4.0, google-drive-api

I'm trying to query a list of the first 10 files from my Google Drive.  Along with the files I want to get the directory it resides in...

There has got to be a better way to do what I'm after.  Currently I call `FindFiles()` and that function calls `GetDriveObjectParentPath()` to get the parents path of each file.  Because of the loop in `GetDriveObjectParentPath()` when it calls itself I run into a **`User Rate Limit Exceeded [403]`** error!

Can someone show me a better way to do what I'm after with a full example please?

```
private string GetDriveObjectParentPath(DriveService drive, string objectId, bool digging = false)
{
    string parentPath = "";

    FilesResource.GetRequest request = drive.Files.Get(objectId);
    request.Fields = "id, name, parents";
    Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File driveObject = request.Execute();

    if (digging)
        parentPath += "/" + driveObject.Name;

    if (driveObject.Parents != null)
        parentPath = GetDriveObjectParentPath(drive, driveObject.Parents[0], true) + parentPath;

    return parentPath;
}

private bool FindFiles()
{
    //Setup the API drive service
    DriveService drive = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = m_credentials,
        ApplicationName = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName,
    });

    //Setup the parameters of the request
    FilesResource.ListRequest request = drive.Files.List();
    request.PageSize = 10;
    request.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(mimeType, id, name, parents)";

    //List first 10 files
    IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = request.Execute().Files;
    if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File file in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.Name, file.Id);

            string parentPath = GetDriveObjectParentPath(drive, file.Id);

            Console.WriteLine("Found file '" + file.Name + "' that is in directory '" + parentPath + "' and has an id of '" + file.Id + "'.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No files found.");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Op completed.");
    return true;
}
```

Using the above produces the following API usage for one single run and results in the 403 client error...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine as is. you just need to deal with the 403 Rate Limit by doing things more slowly and retrying. I know it sucks, but that's just how Drive works.

I normally see 403 rate Limit errors after 30 or so requests, so that fits in with your observation.

In terms of approach, whenever I see a question that contains "folder hierarchy", my advice is always the same. Start by fetching ALL folders using a files.list q:mimetype='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'. Then process that list once to build up an in-memory hierarchy. Then go fetch your files and locate them in the hierarchy. Always remember that in GDrive, the "hierarchy" is somewhat imaginary since parents are simply properties of any given file/folder. This means that a file/folder can have multiple parents, and also that the hierarchy can even loop back on itself.

Comment: I updated the question to show the usage results.  Remember, it's not just 10 requests.  It's the 1 for the initial request to get all the files, then it's 1 for EACH parent.  So if the first file is located at `/My Drive/my first folder/second/and final folder/my file.txt` that would result in 4 requests making a total of 5 JUST to get the info for the first file.  That's why I was hoping I could do something different to get the full path of each file rather than submit hundreds of requests to achieve such a simple results.

Comment: Gotcha. I've updated the answer with some additional info. Regardless of what approach you take, 403 Rate Limits are an unfortunate fact of life for GDrive, so you'll need to handle them in your code.

Comment: Ahh that's a great idea!  Make a request to get all the "folders" in a list local to your app, then a request to get all the "files" in a list local to your app.  Do all the comparing and checking internal to your application and not with a bunch of queries!  ;)

Comment: Also..  how do you define the mimeType when doing this with c#?  Is it specified in the request.Fields property?

Comment: re the c# library, sorry i don't know. I try to avoid using closed source libraries. Intuitively I expect it to be something like request.Q = 'mimetype...'